# Single function for Wistia autoplay

Tags: jquery, wistia

I'm relatively new to jquery and have been trying to create a single function for the Wistia video player script instead of stacking the same over and over. Some pages this will be applied to have as many as 20 videos that need specific urls to play each.

Original:

```
wistiaJQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.href.toString();

    // this will autoplay video with url 'www.my-site.com/a-name'
    if (url.indexOf('a-name') != -1) {
    wistiaJQuery('.a-name').click();
    $(".wistia-fancybox #fancybox-overlay").css("display", "block");
    }

    // this will autoplay video with url 'www.my-site.com/b-name'
    if (url.indexOf('b-name') != -1) {
    wistiaJQuery('.b-name').click();
    $(".wistia-fancybox #fancybox-overlay").css("display", "block");
    }

    // this will autoplay video with url 'www.my-site.com/c-name'
    if (url.indexOf('c-name') != -1) {
    wistiaJQuery('.c-name').click();
    $(".wistia-fancybox #fancybox-overlay").css("display", "block");
    }

});
```

Into something like:

```
wistiaJQuery(document).ready(function () {
    function playVideo(selector) {
        $(selector).each(function () {
            var url = window.location.href.toString();
            var el = $(this);
            var vid = function () {
                if (url.indexOf(el) != -1) {
                    wistiaJQuery('.' + el).click();
                    $(".wistia-fancybox #fancybox-overlay").css("display", "block");
                }
            };
            $(el).on('load', vid);
        });
    }
    playVideo('a-name,b-name,c-name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close, just needs a couple of changes to go:

- You need to use [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) instead of [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/). If you do `$('a-name,b-name,c-name')`, you will get nothing because there are no element tags `<a-name>`, `<b-name>`, or `<c-name>`. Split the string into an array, and use `$.each( array, function(index, value) { ... })` instead. Then replace your references to `el` for `value`.
- There's no need to define the `vid()` function and call it when the element is loaded. The element will already be loaded as you are placing the code in `$(document).ready()` (and you were not waiting for it in your original code anyway).

In the end, you could use something like this:

```
wistiaJQuery(document).ready(function () {

    function playVideo(selector) {
        $.each(selector.split(","), function (idx, obj) {
            var url = window.location.href.toString();
            if (url.indexOf(obj) != -1) {
                wistiaJQuery('.' + obj).click();
                $(".wistia-fancybox #fancybox-overlay").css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    }

    playVideo('a-name,b-name,c-name');

});
```